# Setting Camera View in Potree to Match Original Image View Using Reality Capture Data

Tags: javascript, three.js, 3d, camera

I'm utilizing Potree for 3D model visualization. These models are generated with Reality Capture, from which I have obtained camera parameter data. My aim is to align the camera view in Potree to correspond with the original view when a specific photo was captured.

Here is an instance of the data I am working with:

```
"name": "DJI_20230228131209_0041.jpg",
"x": 26.2941,
"y": 32.3176,
"alt": 24.1355,
"heading": -112.0371,
"pitch": -1.1162,
"roll": 44.6601,
"f": 35.9491,
"px": -0.0018,
"py": -0.0006,
"k1": -0.0485,
"k2": 0.046,
"k3": -0.1316,
"k4": 0.0,
"t1": -0.0014,
"t2": 0.0013
```

Below is the function I'm using to try and set the view:

```
const setCamera = (imageName: string) => {
    const imageData = camParam.find((image) => image.name === imageName);

    const boxGeometry = new THREE.BoxGeometry(0.1, 0.1, 0.1);
    const boxMaterial = new THREE.MeshBasicMaterial({ color: 0x00ff00 });
    const boxMesh = new THREE.Mesh(boxGeometry, boxMaterial);

    const position = new THREE.Vector3(imageData.x, imageData.y, imageData.alt);
    boxMesh.position.copy(position);

    function toRadians(degrees) {
        return (degrees * Math.PI) / 180;
    }

    function calculateDirection(yaw, pitch) {
        const direction = new THREE.Vector3();
        direction.x = Math.cos(pitch) * Math.cos(yaw);
        direction.y = Math.sin(pitch);
        direction.z = Math.cos(pitch) * Math.sin(yaw);
        return direction;
    }

    const euler = new THREE.Euler(
        toRadians(imageData.pitch),
        toRadians(imageData.heading),
        toRadians(imageData.roll),
        'XYZ' // This is the order of rotations
    );

    boxMesh.quaternion.setFromEuler(euler);
    viewer.scene.scene.add(boxMesh);

    const direction = calculateDirection(toRadians(imageData.heading), toRadians(imageData.pitch));
    const distance = imageData.f; // Assuming `f` is the focus distance
    const target = new THREE.Vector3().copy(position).add(direction.multiplyScalar(distance));

    viewer.scene.view.position.copy(boxMesh.position);
    viewer.scene.view.lookAt(target);
}
```

The desired outcome is that, on running this function, the view transitions to the location where the image was captured and reflects the precise scene captured in the image on the 3D model. However, the expected behavior isn't being exhibited.

Here is what I have attempted:

- I've ensured that the camParam array has the correct image data.
- I've converted coordinates to match Potree's left-handed coordinate system (Y up) from the right-handed coordinate system (Z up) used by Reality Capture.
- I've converted the heading, pitch, and roll values from degrees to radians.
- I've set the Potree camera's position, direction, pitch, yaw, and radius based on the image data.

Despite these measures, the camera view in Potree isn't aligned with the original photo.

I also have a second file from Reality Capture, which contains data of this sort:

```
"R(0,0)": -0.254,
"R(0,1)": 0.664,
"R(0,2)": -0.703,
"R(1,0)": 0.927,
"R(1,1)": 0.375,
"R(1,2)": 0.019,
"R(2,0)": 0.277,
"R(2,1)": -0.646,
"R(2,2)": -0.711,
"Tx": 2.172,
"Ty": -36.962,
"Tz": 30.78,
"F(pix)": 3041.638,
"Image": "DJI_20230228131209_0041.jpg"
```

In this, R represents a rotation matrix and T represents translation. Although I haven't utilized this yet, it seems like it could potentially be useful.

Does anyone have insights into resolving this issue? Any input would be much appreciated.